# How to calculate woo commerce shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make a API for calculate shipping cost by method's name, How could i calculate shipping cost by methods name and display shipping cost after create order.

Same like this.[image]

Comment: LoicTheAztec, I Knew about this but i want to used in rest API , could you please suggest me how could i used , I also used rest api of WC but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't really know as your question is too vague… But on WC REST API documentation [you need to use the **order fee lines properties**](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-fee-lines-properties) … Also as StackOverFlow is code riented, you should need to provide some code first, to get helped… Remember that questions asking for tutorials are mostly off topic here.

Comment: Also before asking a new question, you should first please give some feed back to the answerers of your other questions [**like this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51340009/3730754). If you don't do it, Answerers tend not to like answering your questions.

Comment: I knew but i want to dynamically display cost of shipping method using REST Api, i have also used place order api but i could not get cost of shipping method.